# Need a good tutorial on asp.net MVC 2 Areas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

Does anyone have some links on some really good tutorials on asp.net MVC Areas?

I found a couple on google, but would like to see if anyone else dug up sommin great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check the official site? http://www.asp.net/mvc

There are lots of interesting videos in Channel 9 msdn

http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/matthijs/Scott-Guthrie-ASPNET-MVC-2/
http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/matthijs/ASPNET-MVC-2-Ninja-Black-Belt-Tips-by-Scott-Hanselman/
http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/matthijs/ASPNET-MVC-2-Basics-Introduction-by-Scott-Hanselman/

Answer (score 2):

There is a walk through on MSDN

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee307987%28VS.100%29.aspx

hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

Personally I always find watching videos better than reading, especially when it comes to code. Check out the monster 60 minute nerd dinner video, after watching that your ready to start ASP.NET MVC

http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/creating-nerddinnercom-with-microsoft-aspnet-model-view-controller-mvc